# How to merge two manifest files in an android project

Tags: android

I have a thirdparty library added in my android project. There are two activities defined in the manifest file of that library project. When I am running the app on the phone, it is crashing saying that activity not defined in the manifest file of my main project. Should I include the activities defined in the manifest file of the library into the manifest file of my project?

Answer (score 0):

Use

`manifestmerger.enabled=true` inside the project.properties file